# Accessing rails application from mobile device

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, mobile, devise

I've developed a simple store application in Rails 3.0 with Devise as an authentication mechanism (only authorized users can access it). I also wrote a native android applicaion, from where I need to login to this web application, authenticate (using email, password) and access the default controller and get the data in JSON format.

So my questions are:

1. How would I authenticate with Rails app from mobile app securely? Can I test this with curl program calling `/users/sign_in`? How would I specify the parameters (email and password)  securely? What is the general convention in this situation?
2. And how do I format data in JSON instead of default XML?

Any ideas? I appreciate your time and thoughts.

Comment: Just wanted to point out similar question thread.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7064803/rails-devise-http-authenticating-mobile

Answer (score 0):

There is some [tutorial](http://lucatironi.github.io/tutorial/2012/10/15/ruby_rails_android_app_authentication_devise_tutorial_part_one/),

Yes you can use cURL to test you RoR app.-

`curl -v -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Accept: application/json' -X POST http://localhost:3000/mycontroller -d "{\"jsonroot\":{\"a_key\":\"something\",\"b_key\":\"someotherthing\"}}"`

To format data in JSON, there are various helpers available in ROR, like to_json and from_json.

Since you have already created the steps, going through this tutorial would be of help to you. Hope the tutorial helps.